# Retrieve values from DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to retrieve a project name from DynamoDB, which is one of my table attributes.

Here is my current code:

```
export async function main(event, context) {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const params = {
    TableName: "dev-table",

    KeyConditionExpression: "userId = :userId" ,
    ConditionExpression: "projectId = :projectId",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":userId": event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
      ":projectId": data.projectId
    }
  };

  try{
    const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("query", params);
    return success(result.Items);
  }catch(e){
    return failure(e);
  }
}
```

But I receive an error:

> Value provided in ExpressionAttributeValues unused in expressions:
>   keys: {:projectId}

Where does this error come from?
How can I retrieve a single attribute value from my table?

Comment: Is ConditionExpression a valid request parameter for the query action? It does not appear in documentation for query here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ConditionExpression** is a valid parameter for deleteItem, putItem, transactWriteItems and updateItem methods. For the query method, use the **FilterExpression** parameter for non-key attributes instead:

```
export async function main(event, context) {
const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
const params = {
        TableName: "dev-table",
        KeyConditionExpression: "userId = :userId",
        FilterExpression: "projectId = :projectId",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":userId": event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
            ":projectId": data.projectId
        }
    };

    try {
        const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("query", params);
        return success(result.Items);
    } catch(e) {
        return failure(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `projectId` starts with `project` that is a [reserved word](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html).

According to [the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html#Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.ReservedWords):

> If an attribute name begins with a number or contains a space, a special character, or a reserved word, you must use an expression attribute name to replace that attribute's name in the expression.

So, I'd try this:

```js
export async function main(event, context) {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const params = {
    TableName: "dev-table",

    KeyConditionExpression: "userId = :userId" ,
    ConditionExpression: "#pId = :pId",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#pId": "projectId"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":userId": event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
      ":pId": data.projectId
    }
  };

  try{
    const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("query", params);
    return success(result.Items);
  }catch(e){
    return failure(e);
  }
}
```